# Manually calculate tz1 address from privatte key/mnemonic

Tags: tezos-client, address

I want to generate a tezos 'tz1' aka manager address from scratch. But I cannot find any detailed algorithm of generation.

For example to generate a ETH wallet we will calculate public key than hash it using keccak256, take last 40 characters of hash add "0x" and you get address.

But I am unable to find similar algorithm for tezos 'tz1' address.
So please help with it.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to apply blake2b hash on the public key;
2. Add the perfix respective to the elliptic curve you are using;
3. Encode the bytes with base58.

Code example from: https://github.com/murbard/pytezos/blob/master/pytezos/crypto.py#L143

```
    def public_key_hash(self):
        """
        Public key hash for this key.
        :return: the public key hash for this key
        """
        pkh = blake2b(data=self._public_key, digest_size=20).digest()
        prefix = {b'ed': b'tz1', b'sp': b'tz2', b'p2': b'tz3'}[self.curve]
        return base58_encode(pkh, prefix).decode()
```